# Cannot send mail to postfix mail server

Tags: email, postfix

I've setup a postfix mail server, my domain points to my server as I'm already hosting the website. However I cannot send any mail to the mail server. I've added the email's such as casper@one3community.com into the postfix file by following a digitalocean tutorial. however on sending the email via my gmail acccount to the postfix server I get this error:

Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

```
 casper@one3community.com
```

Technical details of permanent failure:
DNS Error: 59683476 DNS type 'mx' lookup of one3community.com responded with code NOERROR
59683476 DNS type 'mx' lookup of one3community.com had no relevant answers.
59683476 DNS type 'aaaa' lookup of one3community.com responded with code NOERROR
59683476 DNS type 'aaaa' lookup of one3community.com had no relevant answers.
59683476 DNS type 'a' lookup of one3community.com responded with code NOERROR
59683476 DNS type 'a' lookup of one3community.com had no relevant answers.

----- Original message -----

DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
        h=mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to;
        bh=JC4qsDfs5VfKFONJttdB91zqKc08MClNBAFtbdRHEtY=;
        b=1CVaGRcuO/O2lWGNo0TQCN/EYTOpbHQiK+dJRhPLb+uGyhGuf60562MtIuerbBDrnV
         pPBuqUuBLwoe1v+mcS9n8FEs8Duqj04e3SRIpmL+5z1aX7WY9QNBEQFmxZtC69nAEThE
         2PnpkQKkEvLWp+GPcwGKLuFY9KpjWhGjnKXkcN1X7cZ8Zvz3rSfDO7IkD34YTziWEUie
         pf6o6LWTEFaFPkF5i/PKaITKsgFVnQCkSSwA1bhhbJFaXP9h3LWTW4H/VGToG7INDK2O
         p/ZGTK9o3xK1gKG/DHZCCW35kyszDSwe8yf/W4SgZEzz1VPm46xmw8kLEG5y0bFDT5zj
         Q2rw==
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=1e100.net; s=20130820;
        h=x-gm-message-state:mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to;
        bh=JC4qsDfs5VfKFONJttdB91zqKc08MClNBAFtbdRHEtY=;
        b=DdRk6oy9O0KZHPjNYyliKeWf/stZHyyAg1tWAbTssUAOnh4PCi/6FYvizoHWDUCq11
         E/AE7z6gn/6iyNAZKfrg5IDLerztB2kqziMR0uaSjFiP0gMowPY+aTLdpDu6t9BJp8Ne
         8EIwn9aNF3IssGBV1XkqXmH8vv8cD9Q6vcyRJeFisnNoLR//yY7F1nVMQqzMgFORVusI
         4tZ1nHMKjUWB8kpbG7u6HP2nOzBehCZZeIdrnYbsv6ll9TC4PCR9tnOzU+nF0w2npYbx
         T24eZ0rJWRpfVmZ3S5DJCWeWwnfDrUKh9Ra5t9ewy+AaWqz2b5m/hqukLJltcErdKxbm
         Kusw==
X-Gm-Message-State: ALyK8tJ+hADw3mFiUoJ4Hqzm0vBjUjw/Lr1GldsthykQN/AjjiUhN9y7wK78WyOBfZlfSdQNlUEprt3RznGsQA==
X-Received: by 10.55.164.20 with SMTP id n20mr10487895qke.73.1465746836117;
 Sun, 12 Jun 2016 08:53:56 -0700 (PDT)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.200.36.18 with HTTP; Sun, 12 Jun 2016 08:53:55 -0700 (PDT)
From: Casper Round <64666cjr@gmail.com>
Date: Sun, 12 Jun 2016 16:53:55 +0100
Message-ID: 
Subject:
To: casper@one3community.com
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=001a114fd2ce7f6231053516c7f9

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgjQT.png)

Comment: Nobody will be able to help you until you post here: 1) your postfix config, taken with the command "postconf" and 2) your postfix log corresponding to the misreception of your email (from /var/log/mail or something). In a perfect world you will make second, verbose postfix log with debug level 2, so we will see in detail what is going there. You can hide (scramble) sensitive information there, but do it so we could still relate things. Don't change message identifiers (they're not a sensitive information). And, please, use formatting features, such as code blocks, to make your post readable.

Answer (score 1):

You write:

```
my domain points to my server as I'm already hosting the website.
```

This is wrong, and it is one of your two problems.

The name `www.one3community.com` points to `104.27.163.48`, so far so good.

Mail, however, is sent to the MX record of the domain, and failing that it is sent to the IP address of the domain. There is at the time of writing no MX record and no IP address for `one3community.com`.

If your postfix server was running on the same IP address as your web server, you should add to your DNS:

```
one3community.com IN A 104.27.163.48
one3community.com IN MX 10 one3community.com.
```

However, your second problem is that 104.27.163.48 does not reply on TCP port 25, so the above configuration will not fix your problem. Since the machine replying on port 80 seems to be Cloudflare, you should probably consult with them.

Comment: I added a photo of my DNS records I just updated. Do they seem okay?

Comment: Also would going through cloudflare effect it?

Comment: The screenshot seems OK, what I see in the DNS right now is not as good since the MX cannot be a CNAME. Going through cloudflare will certainly affect things.